# Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpectationException: No matching handler found for Mockery_1_::make

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit

I have written this test that is returning the following error:

> Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpectationException: No matching handler
>   found for
>   Mockery_1_My_Class::make(array('valid_until'=>'2020-03-04',)). Either
>   the method was unexpected or its arguments matched no expected
>   argument list for this method

Now I have this code in my test:

```
$rateValidator->shouldReceive('make')->once()
            ->withArgs([$attributes])->andReturn(mockery::self());

$rateValidator->shouldReceive('addContext')
            ->withArgs(['update_rate_validity'])->andReturn(mockery::self());
```

And This is the code this test is testing:

```
$attributes = [
    'valid_until' => $command->validUntilDate
];

$validator = $this->rateValidator->make($attributes)->addContext('update_rate_validity');
```

What am I doing wrong here? For me the only problem could be in the `arguments` (`$attributes`) that the method `make` is receiving but I cant figure out what that could be?

Comment: The error seems quite clear to me. Sounds like your code is not calling the make function with the values you posted in `$attributes`. Try to do some `var_dumps` in your actual code to see what values you're passing to the `make` function.

Comment: Try using `->withAnyArgs()` to see if the method is called and the test generally works. From there on you can start restricting the args. For example instead of passing the array you can use a closure that checks for the array key or checks if the value is within a range to account for datetime-quirks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure about data you send as a mock. Your sent data type, and data type expected by the called function, must be same.

For example:

Your function expects data as below:

```
[
    'test' => 'test',
]
```

You must send the same data to the function by mock:

```
$validator->shouldReceive('theFunction')->with(['test' => 'test'])->andReturn('xx');
```